# I am having an issue with ruby and rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to the field ,I have successfully in setting up ruby and rails (i checked ruby -v and rails -v to see if they were installed correctly ) .
after this I was able to execute a basic "hello world " rails program .
But after that i closed the terminal and I reopened and tried to start a new program . But now when i type in "rails new" ,it says

```
The program 'rails' can be found in the following packages:
 * ruby-railties-3.2
 * ruby-railties-4.0
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

and the same goes with ruby -v and rails -v . I don't know where i going wrong ?

rvm list command displays :

```
=* ruby-2.2.0 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.2.1 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

Comment: What do you get with `rvm list`?

Comment: Please use a more meaningful question title.

Comment: How did you install Ruby?

Comment: @DaveNewton I have followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hiPQynmnsiI  , i am not sure if that was a good idea

Comment: @NevinSunny, so it solved your problem too! :) Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the same problem after a fresh install of my OS, selecting `Run command as a login shell` in my terminal solved the problem.

```
Terminal > 
Edit > 
Profile Preference > 
Title and Command > 
(Check) **Run command as a login shell**
Restart Terminal
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem here is that you haven't re-entered the program's folder. Try to CD (change directories) to the correct collection of files. You might have also forgotten to add a title for your app when entering rails new

Comment: yes , I have moved to the correct folders , and i have also put int a title .The command I used was "rails new blog" . The thing is even rails -v or ruby -v is not working . I am assuming those are supposed to work no matter what .

Comment: okay i will try that , is there  single command to  wipe out ruby , rails and all its associated files? . so that i can start  fresh . Because this happened before . And i had to re install it in the method i used the previous time .